# SQL - Check how many times substrings within a column appear in within another column of strings

Tags: sql, vertica

For my problem, I'm trying to find the category with the highest count of words within various sentences:

**Table 1:**

| Word | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 'Rain' | A |
| 'He' | A |
| 'France' | C |
| ... | ... |
| 'Work' | B |

**Table 2:**

| ID | Sentence |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 'I'd like to go to France sometime.' |
| 2 | 'He won't come in a rain like this.' |
| 3 | 'They agreed to work together.' |
| ... | ... |

Ideally I would like to create a table like this:

**Result:**

| ID | Sentence | Category with highest word count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'I'd like to go to France sometime.' | C |
| 2 | 'He won't come in a rain like this.' | A |
| 3 | 'They agreed to work together.' | B |
| ... | ... | ... |

My plan was to create columns for each word and then aggregate them by their categories to find the category with the highest word count for each ID, but the code I am planning to use requires a lot of manual input. Is there a better way to do this?

````
select ID, 
Sentence
regexp_count(Assignee, 'Rain') + regexp_count(Assignee, 'He') + ... as CategoryA_Count
... as CategoryB_count
... as CategoryC_count
from Table 2```
````

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly: each word in your sentence may or may not correlate to a word in Table 1 and you want to show the category letter based on the count of words in the sentence? Its a little bit confusing, because if that is the case, your sample data does not reflect your output. I don't see any of the words in Table 1 in your sentences.

Comment: I’ve adjusted the question to make it a bit more clear. 

Basically table 1 is a very large list of words, with each word being mapped to a specific category. But yes, these are two separate tables so they won’t be correlated. The category column on the results table should show the category with the most amount of words that appear within the sentence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could work:

```
WITH
-- your input ...
words(word,category) AS (
          SELECT 'Rain'  ,'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 'He'    ,'A'
UNION ALL SELECT 'France','C'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Work'  ,'B'
)
,
-- your other input ...
sentences(id,sentence) AS (
          SELECT 1,'I''d like to go to France sometime.'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'He won''t come in a rain like this.'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'They agreed to work together.'
)
-- here goes the query ...
-- Each time a word out of "words" is found in "sentences", that
-- counts once. 
SELECT
  id  
, sentence
, category
FROM words
-- "Found" can be expressed as a join of "words" and
-- "sentences" that succeeds if that word is found in a case in-
-- sensitive match ( REGEXP_ILIKE() ) as a word match: "\b" means:
-- word boundary, hence we match with '\b'||word||'\b', so, for 
-- example: '\bHe\b', and not just 'He'. REGEXP_ILIKE() returns a 
-- Boolean: TRUE if a match is found.
JOIN sentences ON REGEXP_ILIKE(sentence,'\b'||word||'\b')
GROUP BY
  id  
, sentence
, category
-- we count the rows produced by the complex join
-- by id, sentence and category. 
-- we use Vertica's analytic limit clause that returns just the
-- first LIMIT <n> rows per partition in the PARTITION BY clause
-- to get the highest COUNT(*), we ORDER BY that value DESC(ending)
LIMIT 1 OVER(PARTITION BY sentence ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
-- out  id |              sentence              | category 
-- out ----+------------------------------------+----------
-- out   1 | I'd like to go to France sometime. | C
-- out   2 | He won't come in a rain like this. | A
-- out   3 | They agreed to work together.      | B
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks! 

Do you think you could briefly explain the logic behind the join on the reflex function? I’m just trying to understand the code

Comment: comments in-line of my edited answer ...